# How to write XPath and CSS for this HTML?

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How do I write the correct Xpath and CSS of the following element - Quick look.

There are multiple quick look buttons on the website, But I am trying to click one of these.

```html
<button type="button" class="cta-button cta-button--small cta-button--quick-look cta-button--nordstromrack"><span class="cta-button__content">Quick Look<span class="cta-button__hidden-text">Nike - Club Crew Neck Sweater</span></span><img alt="spinner" src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="cta-button__spinner"></button>
<span class="cta-button__content">Quick Look<span class="cta-button__hidden-text">Nike - Club Crew Neck Sweater</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath, if you are trying to click on 'Nike - Club Crew New Sweater' quick look button.

```
//span[.='Nike - Club Crew Neck Sweater']/ancestor::button
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see if this is the unique locator without the wider HTML context, but try this as CSS locator:

```
'button.cta-button--nordstromrack'
```